# Will Dropping a corrupt table free up space in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

We have a MyISAM Table in our database which has around 97 Gb worth of data with resulted in 95% disk utilization. Due to this we started clearing the data from the table by deleting the rows but this also did not result in clearing the space.

So we read about firing the Optimize table command, but due to the lack of space the command was interrupted which resulted in the table being corrupted.

Now my question is, if we drop the corrupted table will it free up my disk space?
Also will the drop query require a significant amount of space to execute like optimize query did?

Comment: This probably might be more appropriate with the dba StackExchange.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens?

Comment: The topic might be too broad because there are cases where dropping table does not necessarily free up disk space. However, if you do mysql dump excluding the corrupted table that will work. Or just do full dump with [specific option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-option-summary) like `--force` - since mysqdump will stop if there's an error like "corrupt table", adding `--force` will "Continue even if an SQL error occurs during a table dump".

Comment: @FanoFN So let me clear this up should we take the db dumb excluding the corrupted table, then remove the existing db and then import the db dump sql file??

Comment: Yes @UmangPachaury, so you'll have a new db without the corrupted data.

Comment: See also https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, dropping a MyISAM table does free up disk space.

Dropping a table does not use additional disk space.

Comment: Hey,
Thanks it worked